# creating table beside another table in latex

Tags: tables

How i can create two table in the same line as the  figure below ?[image]

Comment: Simply put  each of them in a cell of a `tabularx{\linewidth}{XX}` environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the two `tabular`s in a `center` environment with an `\hspace` of your choice between them. Make sure you don't have an empty line between the two `tabular`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\hspace{3cm}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```